# Image upload to server android httppost

Tags: java, android

Hi i have so much googled about image upload from android phone to server and i have done following code

for example

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        for (int index = 0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
            if (nameValuePairs.get(index).getName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
                entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(),new FileBody(new File(
                                        nameValuePairs.get(
                                                index)
                                                .getValue()),
                                "image/jpg"));
         httpPost.setEntity(entity);

     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                localContext);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Don't know why but image is not uploded to server and i am getting following logcat

```
      05-08 23:20:17.452: I/System.out(2501): Response from serveer <pre>Array
      05-08 23:20:17.454: I/System.out(2501): (
      05-08 23:20:17.455: I/System.out(2501):     [image] => Array
      05-08 23:20:17.455: I/System.out(2501):         (
      05-08 23:20:17.455: I/System.out(2501):             [name] => IMG_20130101_164850.jpg
      05-08 23:20:17.455: I/System.out(2501):             [type] => 
      05-08 23:20:17.455: I/System.out(2501):             [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php5CD4.tmp
      05-08 23:20:17.456: I/System.out(2501):             [error] => 0
      05-08 23:20:17.456: I/System.out(2501):             [size] => 1988151
      05-08 23:20:17.456: I/System.out(2501):         )
      05-08 23:20:17.456: I/System.out(2501): )
```

Here from server **TYPE is returning no value** so i can not give update

Please anybody can help about this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested and it's fully working

You just need to change

This code to

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

to

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                **HttpMultipartMode.STRICT**);

and it will be done all other code is fine

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that come to mind:

Bad (Eats up memory)

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(...)
entity.addPart("nameOfThePartTheServerExpects", fileBody);
entity.addPart(...) // additional parts if the server needs stuff.
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

Good (Better for memory)

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(is, someRandomFilename);
entity.addPart("nameOfThePartTheServerExpects", inputStreamBody);
entity.addPart(...) // additional parts if the server needs stuff.
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

I would strongly suggest that you inspect the post from a web page for a normal web implementation so you can see what the names for all the Parts are, those Parts will correspond to all the entity.addPart().

Also your use of FileBody is deprecated, please see the [API](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html).